# binary one on older position in array

Tags: c++, arrays, binary

I need to write a function, which return index of array (integer values),
in which is a value with a binary one on higher position (like number 7: has 0111 in binary representation and e.q: 19 is 10011 so index of this number(19) should be returned in function ) than in values from others postions in array.

What Should I do in the first step? Need I go through all values in one FOR loop, and second FOR loop to check and compare with other values from rest numbers in array?

Input: tab[1,2,7,19];
Output: 3 -> this is index of 19 because this is a number which has binary one on higher position than others.

```
int value(int tab[], size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 31; j >= 0; j--)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not clear what you want to do. Can you give an example?

Comment: can you pls explain this?: in which is a binary one on older position than in values from others postions in array.

Comment: What do you mean by *binary one on older position*?

Comment: @tobi303 I edited my post. Is it clear at now?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is higher bit position. In 0001, the 1 is in the lowest bit position, and in 1000 the 1 is in the highest bit position.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the requirement here is. If you have three values, 15, 16, and 17, both 16 and 17 have a higher bit with a 1 value than 15. But they both have the same high bit. Which one should be returned? If it's 17, then this just sounds like finding the largest value in the array.

Comment: if you found a solution you should post it as answer not in the question. Questions are for questions not for answers

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h> 

int value(int* tab, size)
{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< size; ++i) //this loop gets me the biggest bit number
    {
        result |= tab[i];
    }
    int bitposition = static_cast<int>(std::log2(result));
    int mask = 1 <<bitposition;
    for(int i = 0; i< size; ++i)
    {
        if(tab[i] & mask)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

This code returns the first number with the biggest bit

Answer (score 0):

You could just get the index in the array that you want, then convert that to a binary number. You could then store those values in a temporary array and use those to find the other ones? If I understand your question, then here is some code that just prints out the binary. Alter it to return the value for another function if that is what you would prefer.

```
void Convert(unsigned int val){
   unsigned int mask = 1 << (sizeof(int) * 8 - 1);

   for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(int) * 8; i++){
      if( (val & mask) == 0 )
         cout << '0' ;
      else
         cout << '1' ;

      mask  >>= 1;
   }
   cout << endl ;
}
```

Comment: I have a code: void value(unsigned int tab[], const int r){
unsigned int mask=1;
int z=0;
int tabx[r];
    for(int j=0; j<r; j++){
        for(int i=31; i>=0; i--){
            if(((tab[j]>>i)&mask)==1){
                tabx[j]=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<r; x++){
        if(tabx[x]>tabx[z]) z=x;
    }
    for(int x=0; x<r; x++){
        if(tabx[x]==tabx[z]) cout << x << ' ';
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

I've got a solution:

```
void value(unsigned int tab[], const int r){
unsigned int mask=1;
int z=0;
int tabx[r];
    for(int j=0; j<r; j++){
        for(int i=31; i>=0; i--){
            if(((tab[j]>>i)&mask)==1){
                tabx[j]=i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    for(int x=0; x<r; x++){
        if(tabx[x]>tabx[z]) z=x;
    }
    for(int x=0; x<r; x++){
        if(tabx[x]==tabx[z]) cout << x << ' ';
    }
}
```